# Livewire Laravel - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttributeNames' of null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm fetching data from Ajax after sending a form. There is a listener that is setting the attribute to my component.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display my results after having submitted the form.
In the component, the model has been well retrieved but when I would like to display it to my component, I get an error.

```
directive_manager.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttributeNames' of null
    at _default.value (directive_manager.js:26)
    at new _default (directive_manager.js:6)
    at new DOMElement (dom_element.js:12)
    at Function.value (dom.js:36)
    at Component.get (index.js:56)
    at Component.value (index.js:272)
    at Component.value (index.js:246)
    at Component.value (index.js:182)
    at Component.value (index.js:158)
    at Connection.value (index.js:30)
```

**index.blade.php**

```
   <div id="results-products" class="results-products">
        <livewire:charts-products>
    </div>

....
<script>
...
var product= fetchData(url);
window.livewire.emit('set:product', product)
...
</script>
```

**charts-products.blade.php**

```
<div>
    @isset($product)
    @foreach ( $product->category as $category)
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4>Product category</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @endisset

</div>
```

**ChartsProducts.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;

class ChartsProducts extends Component
{

    public $products;

    protected $listeners = [
        'set:product' => 'setProduct'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.charts-products');
    }


    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product= Product::find($product);
        //I have checked and the assigned variable is ok
    }


}
```

The products is a model and has a relationship Category.

Is there something that I missed ?

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the way the dom-differ inside Livewire behaves. Try adding a key to the loop item

```
<div>
    @isset($product)
        @foreach ($product->category as $category)
            <div class="card" wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>Product category</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
         @endforeach
    @endisset
</div>
```

See the troubleshooting in the docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/troubleshooting

Also, change your public property from `$products` to `$product`